# how to pull changes made (by another person) on the current branch?

Tags: git

I'm a little bit new to git tried to find solution here but did not succeed.
I'm on a branch that has some modified files by someone who is on the same branch.
the person modified the files and pushed them, I'm trying to get the files using pull command (after performing fetch) but it tells me :

> "There is no tracking information for the current branch.
>   Please specify which branch you want to merge with"

the problem I did not made any changes on my PC to the code so what can I do to get the files ?

- I have to say that using git status I can see the modified files

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used?

Answer (score 1):

Try `git pull origin [branch name]`

Edit: Here the (modified) explanation from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) :

Update the remote-tracking branches for the repository you cloned from, then merge one of them into your current branch:

```
$ git pull
$ git pull origin
```

Normally the branch merged in is the HEAD of the remote repository, but you can specify any remote branch by adding a name.

Example:
Merge into the current branch the remote branch `next`:

```
$ git pull origin next
```

This leaves a copy of next temporarily in FETCH_HEAD, but does not update any remote-tracking branches.